# Is there a way to automatically load the new data updated from my xammp server into my console log without using the set Interval function

Tags: php, angularjs

I want the data to get automatically updated when a new data get updated in the database without using the SET Interval function.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);

function myTimer() {
    $http.get('URL CALL', { params: { "key1": "value1"} })
         .success(function(data) {
             document.getElementById('available').value=data.status;
         })
}
```

Comment: The [`.success` method is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339) avoid using it in new code.

Comment: okay thanks @georgeawg

Answer (score 1):

Without `setInterval` function, Then try `setTimeout`... Just LOL...
Without `setInterval` & `setTimeout` you can do it with `websocket`.

In industry, When you want to deal with real time process It's good to go with websocket.

[Read More about websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)